# How do I convert an ArrayList of generics (T) to a straight array?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

First time using generics.

I've successfully created an ArrayList of generic objects, and I would like to convert it to a regular array `T[]`.

Normally, this is something like

```
String[] x = (String[])myStrings.toArray(new String[0])
```

However, in this case, replacing String with `T` does not work. i.e.

```
return (T[]) ret.toArray(T[0]);
```

Here is complete code for my method, tho not sure it is relevant:
https://puu.sh/AzxKD/f525bdbe77.png

Comment: Hint: in the other question, read the "Checked" part, as you do have access to `Class<T>`  in your method

Comment: Note the signature of `List.toArray(target)`: `<T> T[] toArray(T[] target)`. That means in `(String[])myStrings.toArray(new String[0])` the cast is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an array with `new T[size]` for a generic type variable `T`. Java doesn't support it.

You can cast an `Object[]` array to `T[]`, and for most purposes that's fine.

In this case, that would be:

```
return (T[]) ret.toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you - So there is no other way but to return an array of Objects? I feel this defeats the purpose as I will not have t o convert this Object array to the correct class type

Comment: I ended up working around this cast with the following:
`code`
        T[] rett = (T[])Array.newInstance(thisClass, ret.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < rett.length; i++) {
            rett[i] = thisClass.cast(ret.get(i));
        }
`code`

Comment: @GregBengis It is not very helpful to try and put code in comments, but yes, if you have access to a `Class` object then you can use `Array.newInstance`.

Comment: Yeah the code was a fail.. haha. Tho it wasn't too much. Thanks for your help, learning a lot about this stuff..